# how to hide items from switch statement in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ng

I'm learning Angular and wondering how I can't hide some item and show certain items only when the user select specific item in the drop down list.

For example, In my page, I have Chart TextBox, Text TextBox, Grid TextBox and a drop down list that contain Chart, Text, and Grid. when ever user select Text, I want to show only Text TextBox and hide the rest.

right now, the three chart type options are showing on drop drop list when ever I run the project but it's not doing anything when I select Text and also I got an error on my ngIf saying that

"Property 'text' does not exist on type 'ChartType'."

I would be really appreciate if can somebody teach me or help me.

The problem I have is in the project I found from from github, the data for drop down list is in the another file called chart.model.ts and it written like this

```
export class ChartUtil {
    public static getChartTypeDisplay(type: ChartType): string {
        switch (type) {
            case ChartType.chart:
                return "Chart"
            case ChartType.text:
                return "Text";
            case ChartType.grid:
                return "Grid";
            default:
                return "unknown";
        }
    }

}
```

and display it like this

design.component.ts

```
 chartTypes: TypeListItem[] = [];

  setupTypes() {
    let keys = Object.keys(ChartType);
    for (let i = 0; i < (keys.length / 2); i++) {
      this.chartTypes.push({ value: parseInt(keys[i]), display: ChartUtil.getChartTypeDisplay(parseInt(keys[i])) })
    }
```

html

```
        <ng-container *ngIf="chart.chartTypes == chartTypes.text">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Text</mat-label>
                <input matInput />
            </mat-form-field>
```

I can't uploaded the full project on stackblitz but I uploaded all the code from those file over https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dmf3vn

Comment: Can you also include the app module in the stackblitz url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normally how you would tackle a ng-switch

**Component Code (badly done)**

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class ChartType  {
  chart =  1;
  text =  2;
  grid =  3;
}


export class TypeListItem {
  public value = 0;
  public display = '';
  public chartType = -1;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public chartTypesEnum = new ChartType();
  public chartTypes: TypeListItem[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    let keys = Object.keys(this.chartTypesEnum);
    for (let i = 0; i < (keys.length ); i++) {
      this.chartTypes.push(
        { 
          value: parseInt(ChartType[keys[i]]), 
          chartType: this.chartTypesEnum[keys[i]],
          display: `This is a ${keys[i]}`
        })
    }

  }
}
```

**HTML (again badly done but simple)**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let chart of chartTypes">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="chart.chartType" >
  <div *ngSwitchCase="chartTypesEnum.chart">Chart</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="chartTypesEnum.grid">Grid</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="chartTypesEnum.text">Text</div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

**Example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bievwr

**Example 2**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhv4bq

Comment: Hi thank you so much for tyring to help me but I still don't know how to get the idea from your code and implement it so please can you take a look at another post I make with more details so that you might be able to help me. thank you so much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62055715/how-to-display-only-certain-items-in-angular

Comment: I can help if you can create a more complete example with stackblitz

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not sure If I can make the stackblitz to work since there are alot of code in the file that  are referring to anther files. I've included more code that are related to my question in my new post so can you please take a look at it and let me know if you need more. thanks

Comment: Can you provide your declaration of `ChartType` and `TypeListItem` ?

Bare models will be adequate

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I think I included that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62055715/how-to-display-only-certain-items-in-angular, please let me know if I didn't. thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had to refresh the page

Comment: oh ok..thank you so much. please let me know if you need more code or more details.

Comment: K check this one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhv4bq

Comment: I added Example 2 as well, You can also segment them inside additional `ng-container`s and reduce the *ngSwitchCase statements

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciated your help. Seriously I was almost in tear.If you don't mind one last quick question, what if I want one particular textbox to always show when the user click either Text or Chart?. I did *ngSwitchCase="chartTypeEnum.chart && chartTypeEnum.text" but some reason it's not working. thanks

Comment: Nah, just place it outside and `*ngIf` it example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rvrsgr

Answer (score 0):

This solution will render an Angular Material dropdown List using Enum with the ChartTypes insted of the your switch.

The Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export enum ChartTypes {
    Chart = 'Chart',
    Text = 'Text',
    Grid = 'Grid',
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-select-by-type',
    templateUrl: './select-by-type.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./select-by-type.component.css']
})
export class SelectByTypeComponent implements OnInit {

    // create an enum variable to work with on the view
    chartTypes = ChartTypes;

    // initialize the dropdown to a default value (in this case it's Chart)
    chartsValue: string = ChartTypes.Chart;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

The View:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-select required [(value)]="chartsValue">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let chartType of chartTypes | keyvalue" [value]="chartType.value">{{chartType.value}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-label>Chart Type</mat-label>
</mat-form-field>

<ng-container *ngIf="chartsValue === chartTypes.Text">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Text</mat-label>
        <input matInput />
  </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="chartsValue === chartTypes.Chart">
    Chart In Template
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="chartsValue === chartTypes.Grid">
    Grid In Template
</ng-container>
```

Comment: hi just edit and included my drop down list. thanks

Comment: test the new updated version of my answer, now it's working with Angular Material, your dropdown and the same Enum as before.